# Dativ Singular "seinem Kollegen"

Tags: grammar, dative

> Herr Knoll schreibt seinem Kollegen einen Brief.

Warum hängen wir "-en" an Kolleg dran?

(Kolleg ist Singular)

Answer (score 10):

`Kollege` ist eines der schwachen männlichen Nomen. Das heißt im Akkusativ, Dativ und Genitiv erhalten diese Nomen ein -(e)n

> Sind Sie Tourist?
>
> Ich kenne einen Touristen.
>
> ---
>
> Wie ist dein Name?
>
> Erkennst du meinen Namen?

[Diese](http://www.pauljoycegerman.co.uk/abinitio/chap11-9.html) Webseiten [erklären](http://www.mein-deutschbuch.de/grammatik/nomen/n-deklination.pdf), wie man wissen kann, was für Nomen schwach sind (Nationaltäten, Personen, Tiere, Wörter mit bestimmten Endungen)

Comment: @mina: bitte. Wenn die Erklärung dir geholfen hat, vergiss nicht, sie zu akzeptieren.

Answer (score 5):

Nein, *Kollege* ist Singular Nominativ, *Kollegen* Genitiv, Akkusativ, Dativ oder Plural Nominativ.

> - Wem also schreibt Knoll einen Brief? Richtig, seinem Kollegen.
> - Wen beleidigt Knoll in seinem Brief? Richtig, seinen Kollegen.
> - Wessen Tasse benutzt Knoll heimlich? Die seines Kollegen.
> - Wen trifft Knoll im Team-Meeting? Er trifft seine Kollegen.
> - Und wem sagt er bei der Gelegenheit, daß sie alle Versager sind?
>     Seinen Kollegen.

Comment: I would give +2 for the funny examples ;-)